# Django Test Update View(edit) error(AssertionError: 'Test Description' != 'Edited Test Description')

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-views

I wrote an edit test, the response status code is working very fine which is `302` but I went ahead to assertEquals to the updated content but it was throwing assertion error.

**MODELS**

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150 , unique=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='banner-images/')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)

  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super(Banner, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**VIEWS**

```
#login view 
def loginPage(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
             
    return render(request,'registration/login.html', context)


#edit banner view
@login_required(login_url='login')
def editBanner(request, slug):
    banner = get_object_or_404(Banner.objects.all(), slug=slug)
    if request.user == banner.user:
        form = BannerForm(instance = banner)
        if request.method =="POST":
            form = BannerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = banner)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('home')
        context = {'form':form, 'banner':banner}
        return render(request, 'edit-banner.html', context)
    return redirect('home')
```

**URLS**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('banner/<slug:slug>/edit/', views.editBanner, name='edit-banner'),
]
```

**TEST**

```
def test_edit_banner(self):
        new_banner = Banner.objects.create(
            name='The Test Banner',
            description='Test Description',
            category='testcategory',
            user= self.user,
            slug= 'the-test-banner',
            tag='testtag',
            image='testimage.jpg',
        )
        response = self.client.post(reverse('edit-banner', args=['the-test-banner']), {
            'name': 'The Test Banner',
            'description': 'Edited Test Description',
            'category': 'testcategory',
            'user': self.user,
            'tag': 'testtag',
            'image': 'testimage.jpg',
        })
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
        new_banner.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEquals(new_banner.description, 'Edited Test Description')
```

But I keep getting this error after many tweaking
[image]

I want to get the description of the edited version of the banner, thanks.

Comment: Can you share how you logged in the user and what `request.user == banner.user` returns?

Comment: For logging in, I created a login function in the views.py. I would add the function to the question above. And `request.user == banner.user`  means that the current user must be the creator or the owner of the banner to edit it.

Comment: Yep did `request.user == banner.user` return true?

Comment: I don't know but based on the test, I used one User for all the testing both for creating the banner, logging in and out.

Comment: Im suspecting the user isn't logged in at all in your test. Can you try to add `self.client.force_login(self.user)` right before `self.client.post()`

Comment: Okay, I would try that and reach out to you concerning the result or outcome. Thanks 

Comment: I tried it but that's not actually the issue. It is still showing me the same error